# Elasticsearch Rollup Job - New data not rolled

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've created an ElasticSearch Rollup Job with the following configuration:

(Please ignore the terrible name, this is just for testing)

[image]

As you can see, the delay of the Job is 1 minute and the job should group data by 5 minutes. Furthermore, I'm looking for the index "kong".

Look at Kong Data View:

As you can see, there's data for today (2023-04-13).
[image]

The problem lays here:

There's no data for today on my Rollup Data View.

[image]

What's going on? Is this an Elastic behavior?